# Tag hygiene - quotation marks as punctuation v. quotations as famous sayings

Tags: discussion, tags

If you look at everything tagged [quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes), it's a mix of questions about the punctuation mark and questions about famous sayings.

It might be useful to tidy this up and split them out. What about:

**for the famous sayings:**
[quotes-sayings] or [sayings] or [aphorisms]

**for the punctuation**:
[quotation-marks] or [quote-marks] or [quotes-punctuation]

Comment: I see the problem, and I am trying to think of a good distinction that would be unambiguous (should one exist).

Comment: This is an excellent question!  But when we do find the perfect unambiguous way to distinguish these tags, what tag would we give to a question like: *I am quoting a remark from Quine in which both styles of quotation marks “”, ‘’ are already used.  How should I punctuate this within my main text?* :-P

Comment: @PLL: Both tags? (quotation-marks tag first)

Answer (score 6):

Taking suggestions from the question: **[quotations]** vs. **[quotation-marks]**?

On the one hand, each individually suggests the right thing pretty unambiguously — “ ” often get called *quotes*, but I’ve never heard them called *quotations*.  On the other hand, since they start (and mostly continue) the same way, whenever you start typing either one, both will come up on autocomplete; and then, with them side by side, the distinction should be clear even for less experienced speakers of English?

On the flip side, this similarity has the drawback that a slip of the keyboard could easily lead to mis-tagging.  But I imagine that’d be a much less common source of error than misunderstanding the terminology — and also, if the terminology is clear, then accidental mis-tags will be noticeable to readers, so will quickly get corrected.

Comment: I'd add [quote-marks] and [quotes] as synonyms.

Comment: I like this too, and have proposed tag wiki pages for `[quotations]` and `[quotes]` accordingly. (`[quotation-marks]` doesn't exist yet, so I couldn't propose anything for it.) One thing, though: what about questions regarding block quotations with no quotation marks?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps "quotes" versus "quotations"?

Comment: But which is which?

Comment: @Kosmonaut - same thought occurs to me. Actually makes the situation a little bit worse if there are two tags and each tag has a mix of both types of question.

Comment: I think the main problem with this is that **[quotes]** is completely ambiguous, regardless of what it’s paired with: it just describes both categories too well.