# The meaning of, and the wiki for, the [quotes] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [quotes] is

> A hopeless mixture of questions about [semi-]famous quotations and questions related to quotation marks.

While this may be true, should we really describe our tags as being a 'hopeless mixture'?

This also brings up the larger question of what the true meaning of the tag is. To me, it should really be about quotation marks, although I guess there might be good on-topic questions about famous quotes too. The problem though is that we end up with [questions like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46379/did-einstein-actually-say-the-fish-quote-that-everyone-is-attributing-to-him-on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather use [quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes) when referring to quotes, and [quotation-marks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-marks) for the quotation marks. The word *quotes* could be referring to the quotation marks too, but such ambiguity should not be reflected in tags, as questions about famous quotes are different from questions about quotation marks.
Rather than creating more confusion with the tag wiki, we should make clear in the tag wiki of every of such ambiguous tags what is their intended usage.

The issue has been raised in [Tag hygiene - quotation marks as punctuation v. quotations as famous sayings](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/500/tag-hygiene-quotation-marks-as-punctuation-v-quotations-as-famous-sayings), but it seems nothing has been done to resolve the ambiguity of usage for [quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes).